# How do I turn my form into an ember component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have this form:

```
<form {{action 'resetPassword' on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="password" value=newPassword placeholder="reset password"}}<br>
  {{#if newPassword}}
    {{input type="password" value=confirmPassword placeholder="confirm password"}}
    {{#if passwordOK}}
      <button>Reset</button>
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
</form>
```

It relies on the resetPassword action being available and also the passwordOK function which tests that a password has been entered and that the confirmation matches.

This is all smashing but I think I need to use this form multiple times in my app. So I assume I should make it into a component.

How can I turn this form into a reusable component?

I'm interested in how to take this chunk of functionality and make it available throughout my app. How do I package this up and re-use it?

Comment: Are you asking where to put the js code for the component?

Comment: I'm interested in how to take this chunk of functionality and make it available throughout my app. How do I package this up and re-use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly late for this party but it may help someone else.

**A 5 Minute Guide to Creating an Ember Form Component With Ember CLI**

1. Generate a new project - "ember new quick-form"
2. Navigate into that directory then type - "ember g component password-component"
3. In your project directory, go to app > components > password-component.js. There, replace the code with this:

   ```
   import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Component.extend({  
     passwordOK: function(){
       return this.get('newPassword')===this.get('confirmPassword');
        }.property('newPassword','confirmPassword'),

   actions: {  
   resetPassword: function() {  
     alert(this.get('newPassword'));  
       }    
     }  
   });
   ```
4. Go to app > templates > components > password-component. There, replace the {{yield}} with this:

   ```
   <form {{action 'resetPassword' on="submit"}}>  
     {{input type="password" value=newPassword placeholder="reset password"}}<br>  
       {{#if newPassword}}  
         {{input type="password" value=confirmPassword placeholder="confirm password"}}  
           {{#if passwordOK}}  
             {{input type="submit" value="submit"}}  
           {{else}}  
           passwords don't match  
           {{/if}}    
       {{/if}}  
   </form>
   ```
5. In app > templates > application.hbs, add the component you've just created by simply adding this: "{{password-component}}"
6. Build your project ("ember s")
7. Your component should be visible. Adding content to the input field and clicking on submit, should show up the contents of what you just typed in.

Comment: This is usually how I do it. What I wonder, is if the component has the `tagName: 'form'` as it's root element - then how would you keep the actions in tact - as far as attaching them to the js instead of the hbs?

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways.

### Solution 1

This is the most basic solution.

Component JS:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import layout from './template';

export default Component.extend({
  layout,
  tagName: 'form'
});
```

Component template:

```
{{yield}}
```

Usage:

```
{{#my-form submit=(action "resetPassword")}}
  {{input type="password" value=newPassword placeholder="reset password"}}<br>
  {{#if newPassword}}
    {{input type="password" value=confirmPassword placeholder="confirm password"}}
    {{#if passwordOK}}
      <button type="submit">Reset</button>
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
{{/my-form}}
```

When calling your `resetPassword` action, it will be passed an event object and you will need to call `preventDefault()` on the event.

```
  actions: {
    resetPassword(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stops page from refreshing
      // do stuff
    }
  }
```

### Solution 2

Here's a more complex example. You'll probably want to handle `e.preventDefault()` internally. This component submits its action asynchronously.

Component JS:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import layout from './template';

export default Component.extend({
  layout,
  tagName: 'form',
  isSubmitting: false,
  onSubmit() { /* pass this in */ },
  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.set('isSubmitting', true);

    Ember.run.later(() => {
      this.set('isSubmitting', false);
      this.onSubmit();
    }, 500);
  },
});
```

Component template:

```
{{yield (hash isSubmitting=isSubmitting)}}
```

Usage:

```
{{#my-form onSubmit=(action "resetPassword") as |form|}}
  <fieldset disabled={{form.isSubmitting}}>
    {{input type="password" value=newPassword placeholder="reset password"}}<br>
    {{#if newPassword}}
      {{input type="password" value=confirmPassword placeholder="confirm password"}}
      {{#if passwordOK}}
        <button type="submit">Reset</button>
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
  </fieldset>
{{/my-form}}
```

In this example, your form will pass an `isSubmitting` property to its parent block template through the `form` variable.

In addition, your `resetPassword()` action will not need to be modified and can stay as is.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is what you looking for.
Basically your form component is declare below and you can access from anywhere by just calling your component id {{sign-form}}

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="form">
    {{signup-form}}
</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/signup-form">
    <form {{action 'resetPassword' on="submit"}}>
      {{input type="password" value=newPassword placeholder="reset password"}}<br>
      {{#if newPassword}}
        {{input type="password" value=confirmPassword placeholder="confirm password"}}
        {{#if passwordOK}}
          <button>Reset</button>
        {{/if}}
      {{/if}}
    </form>
</script>
```

Comment: OK, so this is a handlebars template - you are suggesting I don't need a component? Does this still work with the action and the passwordOK function? Do these just need to be available wherever I use the template?

Comment: this component is only available to any view in specific file.. if you want to access this component from anywhere in your application then you have to create a global component. Any action happening inside the component will work the same way as it was outside the component.

Comment: handlebars make development easier i definitely recommended check this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-handlebars--net-27761